# Sitecore 8: Workflow issue

Tags: sitecore, workflow, sitecore8, content-editor

I have an issue in workflow while triggering fast approve.

Steps:

1)Through Content editor, i edit an item.

2) I click on Fast approve button which pops up a comments window

[image]

3) On clicking OK or Cancel button, the UI is somehow refreshed and the content tree is now collapsed to base level "sitecore/content/ First-Node-Under-Content".

I am unsure why and what is causing this behavior. Also, I have created and applied workflow which is using in-built fast approve functionality.

This issue exists only in Firefox and IE .

Comment: Can you explain the Workflow, all its states and actions? Is this Fast Approve Action a custom one with custom code?

Comment: @JonathanRobbins we have three states Draft, Awaiting approval and Approved and their commands:
1. Draft has Submit ,Save to draft ,Fast Approve and UpdatChildItemWorkflow.
2. Awaiting approval has approve, Fast Approve ,reject and UpdatChildItemWorkflow
3. Approved has an AutoPublish and UpdatChildItemWorkflow.

And the validationAction for "Submit" and "Approve" commands.
The "UpdatChildItemWorkflow" command is the customized one which changes the child items workflow state after the parent item is approved.

 And the Fast approve action  is not a custom one.